# Layer backed controls and vibrancy?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit

So I did the thing where I put an NSButton inside a NSVisualEffectsView and set the blending mode to "in window". Before I put the button in, I got an error about setting wantsLayer on the visual effects view. I set it to true and it ran the next time. After putting the NSButton on the view however, I got an error, specifically `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Vibrant controls require layer-backing when blurring inside the window`. 
I decided it must be a similar thing so I tried setting the wantsLayer property of the NSButton to true but I still got that error. Does anyone more familiar with Core Animation know the solution to this?